# How to find the right Firebase Version required by spesific @Nuxtjs/Firebase version?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

So this is my problem:

1. I need to install firebase and @nuxtjs/firebase
2. Unfortunately the project I am working on is using vue@3.2.37 and nuxt@3.0.0-rc.6, is too old for the latest version of firebase and @nuxtjs/firebase
3. That means I have to install older version of @nuxtjs/firebase. Now there is a big problem:

1 How to find the right version of @nuxtjs/firebase that is my project can use?

2 and then, how to find the right version of firebase that is usable for point 1 above?

Please someone help, I am still new in this Nuxt / Vue thing. Thank you.

Comment: There's no version of `@nuxtjs/firebase` compatible with Nuxt 3

Comment: ah i see. so i will just find an alternative for it. thank you

Comment: Please check https://modules.nuxtjs.org/?category=Database it looks that supabase is compatible with nuxt3

Comment: actually i need to use the firebase for google authentication. so my user can login with their google account. i am now thinking about this: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup



npm install --save-exact @nuxtjs/auth-next
npm install @nuxtjs/axios

(edit: oops sorry this comment does not support multiline)

Comment: Maybe give a try to this: https://supabase.nuxtjs.org/